# Bash choose option without pressing enter

Tags: bash, shell-script

i have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo -n "Choose an option:
1) Encrypt
2) Decrypt
3) Quit
-> "

read opzione

if [ "$opzione" == "1" ]; then

echo -n "Drag here the file to encrypt: "
read chiaro
...
fi
```

I would like to have the script to automatically accept the number after entering it. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: It should be noted, as part of good scripting practices, that you should *also* make it possible to use your tool non-interactively by passing options on the command line.  For example, `adduser` will allow both interactive or scripted use.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-n chars` option: from `help read`

```
  -n nchars return after reading NCHARS characters rather than waiting
        for a newline, but honor a delimiter if fewer than NCHARS
        characters are read before the delimiter
```

Alternatively, in newer versions of bash you could replace the whole construct with a `select` statement, which implements the selection list for you

```
$ select opzione in "Encrypt" "Decrypt" "Quit"; do echo "You chose $REPLY"; done
1) Encrypt
2) Decrypt
3) Quit
#? 1
You chose 1
#? ^C
```