# How to make a menu without pressing ENTER after choosing the option?

Tags: bash, menu

I'm trying to create a menu in bash but I don't want to press ENTER when selecting the option number.

The code I'm trying to use:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Select a character:"
select character in Sheldon Leonard Penny Howard Raj
do

    echo "Selected character:echo |  $character"
    echo "Selected number:echo | $REPLY"

done
```

Thanks to everyone who helps.

Comment: PS3=Select a character:
select character in Sheldon Leonard Penny Howard Raj
do
    read -n 1
    echo "Selected character:echo |  $character"
    echo "Selected number:echo | $REPLY"
done

Comment: You should post your question in English, you can use some translator for that. However I'm not sure if I may edit your post to translate it only. My native language is not Portuguese, but Spanish so I can understand parts of your question easily.

Comment: Ok man, apologize!

Comment: But my intention is creat a bash select menu without have to press enter after choose the number of desired option. My English is not very well. Thanks!

Comment: No problem (I can understand you correctly)! Regarding your question I'm not sure if you can *modify* the read behavior of `select in`. I will take a look to that!

Comment: Do you have to use `select in`? Because you can create the menu without using `select in` to be able to use `read -n1` to avoid pressing enter.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229439/116858

Comment: @bremaya I edited your question, your line `PS3=Select a character:` actually will result in an error, the correct is `PS3="Select a character:"` (with double quotes `"sometext"`)